# Calculate Average of last X documents in MapReduce

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoose

I even know if mapreduce is the best option for what I need. I have a mongoose document like this:

```
currency { 
   Time: Date,
   Interval: Number
}
```

In my mapreduce job, I want to calculate the average Price (Interval) of the last X documents. (including the current).

If I pass in 20 to my method, I want for every document, calculate  the value of the last 19 + current one, divided by 20.
Any advice or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
function calculateAverages(Schema, interval, avg, callback){
    v
    var o = {};
    o.scope = {interval: interval, avg: avg};

    o.map = function(){

            var value = {
                  Time: this.Date,
                  Interval: this.Interval

            };

            // How am I gonna group the correct number of docs togheter?
            var key= ??

            emit(key, value);


    };
    //  an array of avg ( ex 20) number of items should be passed here
    o.reduce = function(key, intervals){
            var reducedVal = { avg: 0};

            for(var i=0;i<intervals.length;i++){
                reducedVal.avg += intervals[i].Interval;
            }
        reducedVal.avg /= avg;
        return reducedVal;
    };

    o.out = {
      merge: "testing"
    };
    o.finalize = function(key, reducedVal){
        return reducedVal;
    };

    Schema.mapReduce(o, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;

        //console.log(results);
        console.log("mapReduce complete");

        callback(results);
    });
};
```

Comment: MapReduce is not the right option (at all) in this situation. you are passing the random number, 20 in this case, and then at the runtime you need the result based on the parameter passed, Map reduce would work in those situations e.g. in your log file some text is printed every millisecond and you want the total count of some specific world occurred every hour (which is not going to change based on some params as in your case) so you precalculate and keep it with you and when needed just return from that document...For your usecase just go for Aggregation pipeline as suggested by someone...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple aggregation pipeline to get the average, the pipline will follow this steps

1. Sort the documents by the Time field
2. Limit the number of documents
3. Group the documents and get the average

You can try this code below, it's simply create Currency model and send an aggregation query to mongodb, the result is displayed on the console, your collection should be nammed currency on you mongodb server.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var CurrencySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Time: Date,
    Interval: Number
}, {collection: 'currency'});

var Currency = mongoose.model('Currency', CurrencySchema);
// You can change the $limit to specify the number of document

db.once('open', function (callback) {
  var pipeline = [
    {$sort: {Time : -1 }},
    {$limit: 5},
    {$group: {_id: null, average : {$avg: "$Interval"}}}
  ];

  Currency.aggregate(pipeline).exec(function(err, data) {
     console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not sure you understand my situation.
for every  document, I need to calculate the average of the last x documents. so if I have 100k documents, and I specify avg = 5, for every document, i need to calculate ( and save ) the average of the last 5. ( 100k calculations ).
`
example db:
1. 01.01.2010 22:35:00 1.32
2. 2 01.01.2010 22:40:00 1.40
3. 01.01.2010.22.45:00 1.33
`
If I specify avg = 3, then on the third documet, I need to save:
(1.32 + 1.40 + 1.33) / 3, to a new field called avg.

Comment: the $limit option in the pipeline is for specifying the number of documents, and also the $sort option is for taking just the last documents

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna keep using MapReduce, my first approach would be using "GROUP"+X as key where X a numeric value you increment after each group. Declare n=1 in any place you can access and increment it with n++, and when n % avg = 0 then X++/n=1 **after** your emit.

Sorry if I type my example in Java, it's the language I use with MapReduce. But I think it will be easy for you to understand my approach:

```
private int X = 1, n=1;

public map(Text anyKey, YourStructure value){
    int avg = ....; //Recover your avg value here, wherever it is stored.
    emit("GROUP"+X, value);
    if (n % avg == 0){
        X++;
        n=1;
    }else{
        n++;
    }
}
```

And you emit:

```
Doc 1 --> key: GROUP1, value: {.....}
Doc 2 --> key: GROUP1, value: {.....}
...
Doc 19 --> key: GROUP1, value: {.....}
Doc 20 --> key: GROUP1, value: {.....}

Doc 21 --> key: GROUP2, value: {.....}
Doc 22 --> key: GROUP2, value: {.....}
...
Doc 29 --> key: GROUP2, value: {.....}
Doc 30 --> key: GROUP2, value: {.....}

Doc 31 --> key: GROUP3, value: {.....}
...
```

This way you will receive the amount of documents you want in your reduce to calculate your average price.

Hope this helps you.